# micronaut and using the @client to make external calls

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-client

So im trying to use the @client annotation when making external calls..

```java
    @Client("/api/external/call")
    @Header(name = ACCEPT, value = "application/json")
    public interface ExternalCall{
    
        @Get
        MyResponse Call();
    }
```

now im not sure should the @Client be like @Client("http://host") and have the @Get("/api/external/call")

I both but whenever i try to run the app i get the following error

Unexpected error occurred: All possible Introduction advise exhausted and no implementation found for method: MyResponse Call()
io.micronaut.aop.exceptions.UnimplementedAdviceException: All possible Introduction advise exhausted and no implementation found for method: MyResponse Call()

Not sure why this is...

Comment: I haven't seen that error before. There is a [Micronaut HTTP Client guide](https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-http-client.html) and [user documentation](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#clientAnnotation) that should be helpful. Short answer is that the combination of `@Client` and `@Get` should be reachable.

Comment: it works if i use a class and a http client... but i wanted to use the @Get

Comment: Make sure you use correct Get annotation

Answer (score 0):

> now im not sure should the @Client be like @Client("http://host") and
> have the @Get("/api/external/call")

If you had this:

```
 @Client("http://host")
 public interface ExternalCall{
    
        @Get("/api/external/call")
        MyResponse Call();
 }
```

When you invoke that `Call()` method, that should generate a GET request to http://host/api/external/call.

Your question mentions `Greeting serviceAGreeting()` and `MyResponse Call()`.  It isn't clear how those relate to the code you show.

Comment: That was a incorrect copy and paste.... I tried the above but it gives the same message... its as though the implementation has not been generated by micronaut

Comment: btw if i use a httpClient client = new HttpClient()...... i can get it to work... but i wanted to use this interface annotated methof.

Comment: "I tried the above but it gives the same message." - That code is valid and does work.  I expect you have soemthing wrong in your build and/or run configuration.  If you can share a simple sample project which demonstrates the problem I would be happy to send you a PR.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're missing the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```